# good textbook to self-learn systems of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I've taken regular Ordinary Differential Equations. Right now I'm taking Systems of ODEs and the textbook is less than stellar. I was wondering if anyone could point me to a decent self-study book for the subject.

Systems of ODEs: matrices composed of regular ODEs

Example: $\frac{d}{dt}\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
x\\ y
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
a&b\\ c&d
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
x\\ y
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$
Thanks! ^_^

Comment: What textbook are you using?

Comment: @Amzoti I'm using "Ordinary Differential Equations: Systems, Discrete Models, and Chaos" by William Dean Stone.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Differential-Equations-Third-Edition/dp/0127843965/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1381728061&sr=8-1&keywords=handbook+of+differential+equations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to peruse these online and see if they satisfy your needs and tastes:

- Differential Equations and Their Applications, M. Braun
- Differential Equations: A Dynamical Systems Approach (series) by J Hubbard and B West

There are also many excellent books of Nonlinear Equations and Chaos that include systems.

Certainly there are excellent notes and examples you can find online and I would imagine Opencourseware (like MIT). Lastly, if you have a college library, you might want to peruse it and see if there are books that suit your needs.

Comment: You know your ODE's! +1